# Looking for a way to know when to run OPTIMIZE on Delta Lake tables

Tags: optimization, databricks, delta-lake

have Databricks running on AWS, I'm looking for a way to know when is a good time to run optimize on partitioned tables. Taking into account that it's an expensive process, especially on big tables, how could I know if it's a good time to run it and on which tables? Maybe I can create a script that executes once a week and run optimize command only when is needed.

Also, it's a recommended practice to run OPTIMIZE for each partition on the same job that I create the partition?

So I create 2022-02-12 partition then run optimize where partition=2022-02-12, I'm not sure about this because of the "eventual consistency" of S3, maybe the files are not ready as soon as they are loaded and something can become corrupted.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have Data quality check at first place

Comment: I know the information arrived ok, don't know if that is your question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data partitioned by day, then you can run the optimization script daily, maybe one hour after day closes (eventual consistency of S3 doesn't play a role here).  It could be as simple as (consider addign `ZORDER BY` on the most often queried columns):

```sql
OPTIIMZE <table> WHERE partition = (current_date() - interval 1 days)
```

If your workload is append-only, then you don't need to worry about [conflicts](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/concurrency-control.html#write-conflicts).

Besides OPTIMIZE, you also need to have a job that will do VACUUM, because OPTIMIZE will leave old files in-place, and they will occupy space.

Comment: Then there isn't a way to know which tables would benefit by optimize? If not, your solution would work, need to examine the queries looking for JOINS/PREDICATES not using partitions for ZORDER BY. Thanks!

Comment: it usually benefit for fields that are queried most often, used in joins, etc.